# Antlr4 Python3 target visitor not usable?

Tags: antlr4, python-3.4, visitor-pattern

I try to follow the [Antlr4 reference book](http://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference), with the Python3 target, but I got stuck in the calculator example. On the [Antlr4 docs](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Python+Target) it says

> The Python implementation of AntLR is as close as possible to the Java one, so you shouldn't find it difficult to adapt the examples for Python

but I don't get it yet.

The java code visitor has a `.visit` method and in python I don't have this method. I think it's because in java the visit method had parameter overloads of the tokens. In python we have `visitProg()`, `visitAssign()`, `visitId()` etc. But now I can't write `value = self.visit(ctx.expr())` because we don't know what visit to call?

Or am I missing an instruction somewhere?

Comment: Do you know where the documentation of the python ANTLR API is located?

Comment: IF you want to write `self.visit()`, you maybe have to write some kind of dispatcher, invoking the right `.visitX()` based on `ctx.expr()` runtime type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like sometime in the last 3+ years this was fixed. I generated a parser from a grammar and targeted Python 3, using:

```
antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python3 -no-listener -visitor mygrammar.g4
```

It generates a visitor class that subclasses `ParseTreeVisitor`, which is a class in the [antlr4-python3-runtime](https://pypi.org/project/antlr4-python3-runtime/). Looking at the [`ParseTreeVisitor`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/8005cfd090d709856a42d78547aec75a4a7bdbc1/runtime/Python3/src/antlr4/tree/Tree.py#L33) class, there is a `visit` method.

For those interested in working through the [The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference](https://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference) using Python, the [ANTLR4 documentation](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/python-target.md) points you towards this github repo:

https://github.com/jszheng/py3antlr4book

Comment: Using antlr 4.7.2 (the latest release at the time of writing), I still don't get a visitor module/class. This is for both Python2 and Python3.

Comment: UPDATE: I was getting a warning ``error(153): LabeledExpr.g4:3:0: rule start contains a closure with at least one alternative that can match an empty string
`` which was preventing the visitor from being produced. Once fixed, I got what I was expecting.

Comment: @PythonJin You saved my life!! Thanks for sharing the git reporsitory. I was lacking good examples.

Answer (score 2):

The Python2/3 targets do not yet have a visitor implemented. I tried to implement it myself, and a pull request is send to that antlr guy to see if I did it correctly. Follow the pull request here: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4-python3/pull/6

Comment: I am stuck at a similar problem. Do you have any update regarding visitors implementation in python?

Comment: The link for this PR is broken and I wasn't able to find any reference to this in the ANTLR4 repo: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4